# Shell script: assigning & reassigning query columns to multiple variables

Tags: oracle, bash, sqlplus

I've come across a problem at work where I need to query an oracle table, then filter the results based on three business rules. The rows which meet the two positive conditions get flagged as valid and the rows which meet the negative condition get flagged as invalid.

I want to do this:

Query returns resultset with many rows and three columns.

```
sqlplus -s uname/password<<EOF
set heading off
set feedback off
SELECT id, age, date from table_A where no=123;
exit
EOF`

for row in resultset 
do
    v_id=$1
    v_age=$2
    v_date=$3

    fn_do_something $v_age
    fn_do_something_else $v_date

    if [some condition is true] 
        then
            do_this $v_id
    elif [another condition is true]
        then
            do_that $v_id
    fi

done
```

Can someone tell me if linux will let me do the age/date/id assignment like that and what the proper syntax would be?

Sorry I don't have the actually code but I'm at home musing it over.

Many thanks

Comment: Please consider using another more data friendly scripting language like Python or Ruby for this. Bash is great for a lot of things, but this really isn't one of them.

Comment: agree that other languages are probably better, but it also depends on how much you expect this solution to scale, and how "perfect" the results have to be. Are you just trying to get good a 1-off solutions that will look at <1000 records? Maybe keep going this route. Could you get fired for bad results or are you just running a general sanity test? If getting fired is a possiblity, start learning perl/python/p? and set those expectations about how much extra time is needed ;-). Shell or language, you need to spend the time to learn your toolset and various tradeoffs. Good luck.

Comment: Guys thanks for having a look and your comments are appreciated, the specification for this project was finalised before I came on board and I'm more or less locked into using the shell script. @shelter this is a one off build, we generally have better tools for building systems here but this is to help an accounting lady with some of her daily routine. I'll be having a go at this over the course of the day and post the answer if it works.